# Running Selenium geckodriver without generating geckodriver log files

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, robotframework, geckodriver

I have some [Robot Framework](https://robotframework.org/) test suites that use the [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html). I run these tests with Firefox and geckodriver. Whenever I run my tests suites, a `geckodriver-*.log` file is created.

For example, before I run my test suite, I have only my `.robot` file:

```
$ ls
example.robot
```

I then run robot, and the geckodriver log file is generated:

```
$ robot --output NONE --log NONE --report NONE example.robot 
<output of running test suite>
$ ls
example.robot  geckodriver-1.log
```

If I rerun the test suite, a `geckodriver-2.log` file is created, and running the suite a third time generates a `geckodriver-3.log` file, and so on.

How can I run my test suites without any geckodriver log files being created?

I know this must be possible, since it can be done in regular python (without Robot) by setting the `service_log_path` to `/dev/null`, as below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import shutil

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=shutil.which('geckodriver'),
    service_log_path='/dev/null'
)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
driver.quit()
```

**My `*.robot` file for a minimal reproducible example**

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary    run_on_failure=None

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test Case
    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/    Firefox
    Close Browser
```

**Version and OS information**

- Operating system: Linux
- Firefox: 79.0
- geckodriver: 0.26.0
- Python: 3.6.9
- Robot Framework: 3.2.2
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary: 4.4.0

Comment: Why not simply delete the files afterwards using os.remove?

Comment: Of course I can delete the files afterwards, but I would prefer they simply weren't created in the first place. I am running these tests on a computer with an SSD, and I don't want to be wasting writes that I don't need. But even if using writes is not a concern, from a curiosity standpoint I would like to know how to prevent the creation of these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set the `service_log_path` argument for the [`Open Browser`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) keyword to `os.path.devnull`, as below:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary    run_on_failure=None

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test Case
    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/    Firefox    service_log_path=${{os.path.devnull}}
    Close Browser
```

Then `geckodriver` will log to `os.path.devnull` instead of to a file in the current working directory.

**Note**: This example uses [inline python evaluation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation), a new feature in Robot Framework 3.2.